# Pairs of cells in columns in a custom UICollectionView layout

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make something like this with a collection view.

| imageview |

|label| |value|

|label| |value|

So far I have been able to display two sections (the first being the image view, the second being the label), but I'm lost at how to add a second column to the second section. I've been looking around for how to do this but all I've seen are how to make the same type of cell be displayed in columns.

Should these labels and values be different sections where I create different custom cells? And should I be using UICollectionViewFlowLayout to display the two different sections side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the image view a supplementary view of the collection view. Here is a [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/) that can show you how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, it looks much easier to group the cells that way, I'll try it out.